# missing antialias while fade

Tags: jquery

I use Jquery fadeIn effect, but it does not work well in Chrome (neither in IE).
At the end of the animation it lost(gain?) its anti-alias property. See the pictures below.

The large text border will be arched, the small one will be sharp.

[image: anti-alias]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a "feature" of the browser, designed to speed up rendering. If text is not being drawn at full opacity, it will not be anti-aliased. I believe IE9 "fixed" this to include AA on partial-alpha text.